# Transduction with P1 lysate prepared from strain that is proC::Tn10

Tags: molecular-genetics

If I do a transduction with a P1 lysate prepared from a strain that is *pro**C*::Tn10 and the recipient is wild type, will all my recombinants  be ProC- and Tet resistant since the Tn10 is in the *proC* gene?

Comment: Slightly confused by this  - what are you going to plate on after the transduction step?